# Extract JSon Format from Large Text File

Tags: json, regex, sed

**Introduction**

Hi! I'm trying to extract JSon from a 300K line text file that has a combination of Text output and JSon format from HTTP Result. The big size in lines makes it unable to retain the JSon manually.

**Problematic**

Don't have much choice, i probably need to fix it manually using a command-line. Here's how it's looks like inside the file:

```
[2K  100.00% - C: 164148 / 164149 - S: 263 - F: 3686 - dhcp-140-247-148-215.fas.harvard.edu:443 - id3.sshws.me
[2K  100.00% - C: 164149 / 164149 - S: 263 - F: 3686 - public-1300503051.cos.ap-shanghai.myqcloud.com:443 - id3.sshws.me
[2K
[
  {
    "Request": {
      "ProxyHost": "pro.ant.design",
      "ProxyPort": 443,
      "Bug": "pro.ant.design",
      "Method": "HEAD",
      "Target": "id3.sshws.me",
      "Payload": "GET wss://pro.ant.design/ HTTP/1.1[crlf]Host: [host][crlf]Upgrade: websocket[crlf][crlf]"
    },
    "ResponseLine": [
      "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocol",
      "Server: cloudflare"
    ]
  },
  {
    "Request": {
      "ProxyHost": "industrialtech.ft.com",
      "ProxyPort": 443,
      "Bug": "industrialtech.ft.com",
      "Method": "HEAD",
      "Target": "id3.sshws.me",
      "Payload": "GET wss://industrialtech.ft.com/ HTTP/1.1[crlf]Host: [host][crlf]Upgrade: websocket[crlf][crlf]"
    },
    "ResponseLine": [
      "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocol",
      "Server: cloudflare"
    ]
  }
]
```

Several problem to this if using RegEx is:

- It has multiple JSon object
- The Text string that doesn't part of JSon has `[` and `:`

I realize the problem when trying to use `sed` regex.

```
sed '/^[/,/^]/!d'
```

Comment: If you delete all lines with the `^\[.` pattern, the output is valid json.

Comment: Would it be also interrupt ```"ResponseLine": [``` Line?

Comment: The `^` symbol anchors the regex to only match at the beginning of the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove all lines that start with `[` and any non-whitespace char:

```sh
sed '/^\[[^[:space:]]/d' file > newfile
```

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `\[` - `[` char
- `[^[:space:]]` - any non-whitespace chars.

Comment: This is the tricky one, didn't have much idea to get there. Thanks!

Comment: @DaviRidho  Just FYI: I used the non-whitespace pattern to make sure the line with a single `[` char with extra trailing whitespaces is not matched. Also, `d` *deletes* the line where the pattern matched.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to this is; to get advantage for special char. If someone wanted to remove the progress bar from the output and extract only appropiate output:

1. Use `nano <output_file>`
2. You will see that there's new line unicode got readed as `^M^[` in the first text. I assume it's the same as `[crlf]`
3. Use `sed -e "/\^M^[/d"` remove lines that contains specific unicode.

Use `\` to escape `^` as RegEx.

Make sure to always find the pattern readed from the terminal and not inside a text editor app, as some of them couldn't read Unicodes.

Comment: Or pass it through `dos2unix`